# Synchronizing ArrayList for multiple users concurrently

Tags: java, swing, collections, concurrency, synchronization

I am new to concurrency. I want to make sure that multiple clients can access and change the books ArrayList in a thread safe manor. Is the following correct? I am trying to use a simple produce-consume model.

```
protected List<Book> books = Collections.synchronizedList(new ArrayList<Book>());

// producer consumer model
    protected Object[] produce(JTextField input) {
        synchronized (books) {
            if (isInteger(input.getText())) {
                for (Book b : books) {
                    if (Integer.parseInt(b.BookID) == Integer.parseInt(input
                            .getText())) {
                        b.Available = Integer.toString((Integer
                                .parseInt(b.Available) + 1));
                        saveTextRecord();
                        // show on table
                        return toTableDisplayObject(b.toString());
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        return null;
    }

    protected Object[] consume(JTextField input) {
            synchronized (books) {
                if (isInteger(input.getText())) {
                    for (Book b : books) {
                        if (Integer.parseInt(b.BookID) == Integer.parseInt(input
                                .getText())) {
                            b.Available = Integer.toString((Integer
                                    .parseInt(b.Available) - 1));
                            saveTextRecord();
                            // show on table
                            return toTableDisplayObject(b.toString());
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            return null;
    }
```

The front in uses swing which is probably apparent, this front-end is what multiple users will use. isInteger() simply returns a boolean for whether the inputted values as a string is an integer. toTableDisplayObject() is used to turn the ArrayList into a format for swing table usage.

Comment: Taking a step back are all the users going to use the same application instance?

Comment: All users will be using the same instance of the class that the above code is in.

Comment: I would make the list private. Also I would not return null rather would return an empty array. From a concurrency point of view I cannot see any issues however It won't scale well(which may not be a problem).

Comment: Maybe you should consider using Vector:  "Unlike the new collection implementations, Vector is synchronized. If a thread-safe implementation is not needed, it is recommended to use ArrayList in place of Vector."  (Though this only assures the consistency of the Vector itself, not its relationship with other entities.)

Comment: is using Collections.synchronizedList on the ArrayList redundant since I am using a Synchronized block?

Comment: @DavidTunnell, yes it unnecessary to use a vector or synchronized collection wrapper, assuming that you're synchronizing the way across any methods that don't appear in your sample code.

Answer (score 0):

This is a poor design. Only 1 consumer at time can acceess to the resource. Try ReadWriteLock or 2 Semaphores to enance the design.